# Custom info view on google map does not show the image

Tags: android, google-maps

I started with the sample code CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap from here:
[CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap](http://%20https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/tutorials/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap)

I changed it adding an image to the info view. and then I tried to load the image in the getInfoContents

```
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {
            // Inflate the layouts for the info window, title and snippet.
            View infoWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map), false);

            TextView title = ((TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title));
            title.setText(marker.getTitle());

            TextView snippet = ((TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
            final ImageView imageView = ((ImageView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.image));

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.this, R.drawable.my_bitmap;
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });

            return infoWindow;
        }
```

In the code above I used the `Handler`only to simulate what happens when I load the image asynchronously by calling `Places.GeoDataApi.getPlacePhotos`.
The result is that the image is not shown. 
If I call:

```
                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.this, R.drawable.my_bitmap;
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

synchronously everything is fine.
It looks like google Map caches the view creating an image of the entire view. From the doc:

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

How can I set the image in the InfoView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found so far is to load the bitmap in advance and to store it in a cache and then assign the bitmap to the infoview.imageView synchronously.
But this means that I have to load the images in advance.